# Explaining Lisp's dotimes: What is result-form doing?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm looking at the LispWorks [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dotime.htm) on `dotimes` but I don't understand what the third variable `[result-form]` is doing. The examples are as follows:

```
(dotimes (temp-one 10 temp-one)) =>  10
(setq temp-two 0) =>  0
(dotimes (temp-one 10 t) (incf temp-two)) =>  T
temp-two =>  10
```

The Hyperspec says

> ...Then result-form is evaluated. At the time result-form is
>   processed, var is bound to the number of times the body was executed.

Not sure what this is saying. Why is the third variable necessary in these two `dotimes` examples? I seem to be able to leave it out entirely in the second example and it works. My next example (not sure where I found it),

```
(defun thing (n)
    (let ((s 0))
      (dotimes (i n s)
        (incf s i))))
```

Puzzles me as well. What use is `s` serving?

Comment: The result form is simply a form that is evaluated to produce a return value (or multiple) after the looping is done. It's optional (if you leave it out, the return value will be `NIL`). In your last example the variable `S` is used to accumulate the sum of all integers below `N`, which is returned at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Since **dotimes** is a macro, looking at it's macro expansion can make things clearer:

---

Take your first example and expand it:

```
(pprint (MACROEXPAND-1 '(dotimes (temp-one 10 temp-one))))
```

I get the following output: *(Yours may vary depending on the CL implementation)*

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((#:G8255 10) (TEMP-ONE 0))
    (DECLARE (CCL::UNSETTABLE TEMP-ONE))
    (IF (CCL::INT>0-P #:G8255)
        (TAGBODY
         #:G8254 (LOCALLY (DECLARE (CCL::SETTABLE TEMP-ONE))
                   (SETQ TEMP-ONE (1+ TEMP-ONE)))
                 (UNLESS (EQL TEMP-ONE #:G8255) (GO #:G8254))))
    TEMP-ONE))
```

There's a lot going on, but the key thing to look at is that temp-one is bound to the value 0, and is returned as the expression's value (in standard lisp evaluation order).

---

Take the last example:

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(dotimes (i n s) (incf s i))))
```

outputs:

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((#:G8253 N) (I 0))
    (DECLARE (CCL::UNSETTABLE I))
    (IF (CCL::INT>0-P #:G8253)
        (TAGBODY
         #:G8252 (INCF S I)
                 (LOCALLY (DECLARE (CCL::SETTABLE I))
                   (SETQ I (1+ I)))
                 (UNLESS (EQL I #:G8253) (GO #:G8252))))
    S))
```

As you can see S here is treated the same way as temp-one in the example before.

---

Try one without passing the last variable:

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(dotimes (i n) (do-something i))))
```

and you get:

```
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((#:G8257 N) (I 0))
    (DECLARE (CCL::UNSETTABLE I))
    (IF (CCL::INT>0-P #:G8257)
        (TAGBODY
         #:G8256 (DO-SOMETHING I)
                 (LOCALLY (DECLARE (CCL::SETTABLE I))
                   (SETQ I (1+ I)))
                 (UNLESS (EQL I #:G8257) (GO #:G8256))))
    NIL))
```

Notice how NIL is the return value.